# Filter results from Stored Procedure using Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I have a query which I cannot do in Linq, as it uses 2 separate databases. Instead, I have written a stored procedure in SQL Server.

Now I need to manipulate the results.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HealthAndSafety] 
    @EventClass nvarchar(50), 
    @EventDateTime datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT     
       SQLPendingEvent.EventType AS Answer,
       (SELECT Description
        FROM RepairCodes
        WHERE (Code = RepairCodes_1.Code) AND (Type = 'HSQUESTION')
       ) AS HSQuestion, 
       (CASE WHEN RepairCodes_1.Type = 'HSANSWERY' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS HSAnswer, 
       SQLPendingEvent.EventDateTime AS completionDate,  
       SQLPendingEvent.KeyPropertyID, 
       SVSExtract.dbo.Property.Address1 + '  ' + SVSExtract.dbo.Property.Address2 + '  ' + SVSExtract.dbo.Property.Postcode AS Address, 
       SQLPendingEvent.KeyEntityID AS JobNumber, SQLPendingEvent.KeyUserID
   FROM         
      SQLPendingEvent 
   INNER JOIN
      RepairCodes AS RepairCodes_1 ON SQLPendingEvent.EventType = RepairCodes_1.Description 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      SVSExtract.dbo.Property ON SQLPendingEvent.KeyPropertyID = SVSExtract.dbo.Property.KeyProperty
   WHERE     
      (SQLPendingEvent.EventClass = @EventClass) 
      AND (SQLPendingEvent.EventCode = 'EVENT') 
      AND (SQLPendingEvent.EventDateTime > @EventDateTime)
   ORDER BY 
      SQLPendingEvent.KeyUserID
```

And here is my C# code:

```
var eventTable = OnSiteV3.HealthAndSafety(_EventClass, _EventDateTime);
```

First I want to extract from this result a list of distinct UserIDs.

Then I want to filter those results on a column called `UserID`.

Something like this:

```
var userList = eventTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new
        {
            KeyUserID = (string)row.KeyUserID
        }).Distinct();
```

And this:

```
eventTable = eventTable.Where(r => r.KeyUserID == selectedUser);
```

Both these examples here come from a different kind of query, like below, but how do I do it with my stored procedure?

```
var eventTable = (from s in OnSiteV3.SQLPendingEvents
                  join r in OnSiteV3.RepairCodes on s.EventType equals r.KeyRepairCode
                  select new
                          {
                              s.KeyDeviceID,
                              s.UpdateTime,
                              s.EventType,
                              s.EventDateTime,
                              s.EventText,
                              s.KeyUserID,
                              s.EventCode,
                              r.Type
                          }).Where(s => s.EventCode == _eventCode && s.Type == _repairType && s.EventDateTime > _EventDateTime).Distinct();
```

Finally got it working. here is my final code:

```
    OnSiteV3DataContext OnSiteV3 = new OnSiteV3DataContext();

            var eventTable = OnSiteV3.HealthAndSafety(_EventClass, _EventDateTime).ToList();

            if (selectedUser != string.Empty)
            {
                var eventTableFiltered = eventTable.Where(o => o.KeyUserID == selectedUser).ToList();
                gvHealthAndSafety.DataSource = eventTableFiltered;
                gvHealthAndSafety.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                gvHealthAndSafety.DataSource = eventTable;
                gvHealthAndSafety.DataBind();
            }

            var userList = eventTable.Select(row => new { KeyUserID = (string)row.KeyUserID }).Distinct();

            ddlUsers.DataSource = userList;
            ddlUsers.DataTextField = "KeyUserID";
            ddlUsers.DataValueField = "KeyUserID";
            ddlUsers.DataBind();
```

Comment: You should be able to do exactly what you're describing - what errors/bad results are you getting?

Comment: This line: eventTable = eventTable.Where(r => r.KeyUserID == selectedUser); produced this error: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebViewer.HealthAndSafetyResult>' to 'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<WebViewer.HealthAndSafetyResult>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do it in the same way using the Property `ReturnValue` of the stored procedure.

Call the stored procedure like this

```
[Function(Name="dbo.Call me as you want")]
public ISingleResult<YourTableResult> GetSomething([Parameter(DbType="NVarChar(20)")] string param1)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this,         ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), param1);
    return ((ISingleResult<YourTableResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

then tou can use it in others functions in this way

```
ISingleResult<YourTableResult> result =
        db.GetSomething("ParameterValue");

//now you can use the code that you already use like this

    var userList = result.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new
            {
                KeyUserID = (string)row.KeyUserID
            }).Distinct();
```

refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386975%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for documentation

Answer (score 0):

`eventTable` is an `ISingleResult<T>`, which is an interface that extends `IEnumerable<T>` to additionally capture the return value of the stored procedure call.

`Where<T>` accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` (which `eventTable` is), but *returns* an `IEnumerable<T>`.  Since you can't implicitly downcast from an `IEnumerable<T>` to an `ISingleResult<>`,you can't store the result of where back in `eventTable`, and the compiler throws an error.

You have some options:

- make `eventList` an `IEnumerable<HealthAndSafetyResult>`, either explicitly or using `AsEnumerable()`:

  ```
  var eventTable = OnSiteV3.HealthAndSafety(_EventClass, _EventDateTime)
                           .AsEnumerable();
  ```
- store the result of `Where` in a differently-typed variable:

  ```
  var eventTableFiltered = eventTable.Where(r => r.KeyUserID == selectedUser);
  ```

Comment: Looks good but failed on the databind: The query results cannot be enumerated more than once.

Comment: Then you may need to hydrate the raw results to a list using `ToList`.

Comment: Hydrate? Sorry, I don't understand that.

Comment: @SteveStaple "hydrate" = execute the query and bring the results into memory.  `eventTable` is _just a query_.  The SQL doesn't actually execute until you put the results in a data structure or try to enumerate it with `foreach`.

Comment: Sorry - but the error message came from further down. After this: var userList = eventTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new
                {
                    KeyUserID = (string)row.KeyUserID
                }).Distinct();

                ddlUsers.DataSource = userList;
                ddlUsers.DataTextField = "KeyUserID";
                ddlUsers.DataValueField = "KeyUserID";
                ddlUsers.DataBind(); - Error here!

Comment: According to the debugger, userlist is defined as: {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<WebViewer.HealthAndSafetyResult,<>f__AnonymousType0<string>>}. Mayvbe this is why databind gives error.